# what does it mean by "...the ordinal number which immediately succeeds $\mathfrak W$..."

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is from "Theory of Sets" by E.Kamke . This is about the notion of successor .

[image]

What does it exactly mean by "...the ordinal number which immediately succeeds $\mathfrak W$..."

Comment: It is just the supremum of the ordinals in $\mathfrak{M}$.

Comment: @Arthur But $\mathfrak W$ is set , not a ordinal.

Comment: How does the text define "the ordinal number of an enumerable set."